# Extract string from another string

Tags: php, xml, string

I have a problem to extract a string from another string.

I would like to extract this string :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!--  Tests completed in 1036 milliseconds. 6

    tests of 6 passed, 0 failed. 
    --> <testsuite name=" Tests" timestamp="2012-11-19T16:37:10Z" tests="6" failures="0" time="1.036"> <testcase name="dede"
    classname="test1"> </testcase> </testsuite>
```

From this string :

```
2012/11/19 17:37:09.689 - INFO. - début du test 1
2012/11/19 17:37:09.689 - INFO. - début du test 2
2012/11/19 17:38:09.689 - INFO. - début du test 3
2012/11/19 17:39:09.689 - INFO. - début du fr 4
2012/11/19 17:40:09.689 - INFO. - début du de 5
2012/11/19 17:40:48.689 - INFO. - début du de 6
2012/11/19 17:40:49.689 - INFO. - génération du résultat
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
 Tests completed in 1036 milliseconds.
6 tests of 6 passed, 0 failed. 
-->
<testsuite name=" Tests" timestamp="2012-11-19T16:37:10Z" tests="6" failures="0" time="1.036">
<testcase name="dede" classname="test1">
</testcase>
</testsuite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off not dumping the test info at the top and either including them in the XML markup, or not showing them at all.

However saying that you could probably use `strpos` to work out where to start extracting your string from.

```
$start_position = strpos ( $original_string , '<?xml' );
```

Then use the start position with `substr()`:

```
$xml_string = substr( $original_string , $start_position );
```

This isn't tested but should be roughly what you need.

strpos(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php 
substr(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I will try but i think that it will be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using PHP's `substr` function.  I used the `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` line so that the XML will be shown in the browser instead of being converted into XML.  You may want to remove that if you are going to use the string as an actual XML string.

```
$string = '2012/11/19 17:37:09.689 - INFO. - début du test 1
2012/11/19 17:37:09.689 - INFO. - début du test 2
2012/11/19 17:38:09.689 - INFO. - début du test 3
2012/11/19 17:39:09.689 - INFO. - début du fr 4
2012/11/19 17:40:09.689 - INFO. - début du de 5
2012/11/19 17:40:48.689 - INFO. - début du de 6
2012/11/19 17:40:49.689 - INFO. - génération du résultat
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
 Tests completed in 1036 milliseconds.
6 tests of 6 passed, 0 failed. 
-->
<testsuite name=" Tests" timestamp="2012-11-19T16:37:10Z" tests="6" failures="0" time="1.036">
<testcase name="dede" classname="test1">
</testcase>
</testsuite>';
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo substr($string, strpos($string, '<?xml'));
```